# Large image causing sidescroll in Jquery-UI pop-up

Tags: jquery-ui, tinymce

```
<tr width="900px;">
 <td colspan="2">#trim(messages.message)#</td>
</tr>

.dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   draggable: false,
   maxHeight: 600,
   overflow: scroll,
   width: 900,
```

I have inserted a large image over 900px (using tinymce plugin) in width and it causes sidescrolling. How can I prevent this and shrink the image instead

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width of the image to a percentage might fix your problem.
    `<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" class="maxWidthImage" width="100%">`
Or from css:
    `.maxWidthImage{
        max-width:100%;
    }`
This will set the image width to the width of the above element.(when it's bigger than the above element)
In your case this is the dialog.